# Use x:Bind with attached property (showing flyout)

Tags: c#, mvvm, win-universal-app, compiled-bindings

I made "MVVM flyout" based on this post: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/how-to-open-and-close-flyouts-in-universal-apps-using-mvvm/

It is working well. But it is **not working with compiled binding(x:Bind)**

This:

```
 <Flyout local:FlyoutHelpers.Parent="{x:Bind ShowButton}"...
```

insead of this:

```
<Flyout local:FlyoutHelpers.Parent="{Binding ElementName=ShowButton}"...
```

throws strange error while building:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Flyout' to
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement'

Is there any option how to use x:Bind?

Comment: X:Bind doesn't take ElementName. So you can't use in this case

Comment: I am pretty sure it does. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension (10th paragraph in Property path section).

Comment: Yes it does. Sorry I misunderstood. I knew that ElementName option is not there. But didn't know that you can specify it as path..

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is related to the generated code for `{x:Bind}`.

As we know `{x:Bind}` uses generated code to achieve its benefits. And these codes can be found in ***obj*** folder, with names like (for C#) ***<view name>.g.cs***. For more info, please see [{x:Bind} markup exstrong texttension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension).

If you go to ***.g.cs*** file (I used `FlyoutHelper` in `MainPage`,so in my side, it's ***MainPage.g.cs***), you will find the error is in **`Set_FlyoutDemoSample_FlyoutHelper_Parent`** method. This method is generated at compile time, `FlyoutDemoSample` is the namespace of my project. Its name may be different in your side.  
[image]

If we go to the definition of this method, we will find the type of the first parameter in this method is `FrameworkElement`.

```
public static void Set_FlyoutDemoSample_FlyoutHelper_Parent(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement obj, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement value, string targetNullValue)
{
    if (value == null && targetNullValue != null)
    {
        value = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement) global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement), targetNullValue);
    }
    global::FlyoutDemoSample.FlyoutHelper.SetParent(obj, value);
}
```

However when using `FlyoutHelper`, the parameter we set here is a `Flyout`.  
[image]
`Flyout` class is not derived from `FrameworkElement`. So it throws an error: `cannot convert from 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Flyout' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement'`. If we change the first parameter's type to `DependencyObject`, all the codes will work well.

```
public static void Set_FlyoutDemoSample_FlyoutHelper_Parent(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject obj, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement value, string targetNullValue)
{
    if (value == null && targetNullValue != null)
    {
        value = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement) global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement), targetNullValue);
    }
    global::FlyoutDemoSample.FlyoutHelper.SetParent(obj, value);
}
```

However, these codes are generated automatically, if we rebuild this project, we will still get the same error. I'm not sure if this is a potential bug in UWP, but I think there is nothing we can do to fix it. So I'd suggest you still use `Binding` in this special scenario.

Comment: It would be fantastic if Microsoft made this work as you mention.